# Python display numbers without a comma in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, range

below I put the code I would like to get the result like:  `0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ....` but I get this result `[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6000000000000001, 0.7000000000000001, 0.8, 0.9]` how can I remove those zeros after the decimal point?

```
    squares = []
for i in range(10):
    squares.append(i * (0.1))
print(squares)
```

Comment: `0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4` isn't "without a comma"...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
>>> ['{:.2}'.format(i * 0.1) for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the str method `format` to specify how many decimals to display.

```
squares = []
for i in range(10):
    squares.append(i * (0.1))

print(*["{:.1f}".format(s) for s in squares], sep=', ')

0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Sup, Kozinski. Hope you're having a great time.

```
squares = []
for i in range(10):
    squares.append(round(i * (0.1), 1)) #integers will be stored in a proper format
print(squares)
```

Check out this [round function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp)

Comment: Basically, that's the simplest answer.

Comment: @why have you deleted your post?I've spent time to answer, and you deleted